# An initialization failure occurred while attempting to boot from a VHD

Tags: windows-7, vhd

I am creating system image of my windows from ***Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Backup and Restore*** 
[image]

This is creating VHD. That's ok, but I noticed that the VHD created is of dynamic type. I want VHD to be created to fixed size (the actual size used by my Windows). Right now out of 250GB hardisk (C drive) 35GB is consumed only. I want the VHD to be created of 35GB but of fixed type instead of expanding type. Why I need this? It is because I have to use this VHD for booting Windows and in my machine I have only one drive and that is C drive. When I boot my Windows with that VHD I get the following error:

**`An initialization failure occurred while attempting to boot from a VHD.  The volume that hosts the VHD does not have enough free space to expand the VHD.`**

[image]

How can I boot that VHD from the C drive only? **My goal is to create a system image of my OS and boot it from its VHD.**

Comment: Is the VHD marked as read-only?

Comment: @Randolph No, it is not marked as Read only

Comment: The thing is I am not able to find creating fixed type VHD of my windows OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) can capture a running Windows into a VHD, skipping all of the SysPrep/ImageX/WIM hassle. You can run it with command line options or just run it without options for a GUI.

Comment: It is saying "Error snapshotting volumes" when I try to create vhd of my c drive.

Comment: There should be a more helpful error event in the event log. It might give some hints as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

STOP 0x00000136 occurs because [the dynamically expanding VHD must be expanded to full size](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2020922) before it can be used for native boot, but the hard drive doesn't have enough space to expand the VHD to full size.

To create an image of your existing system that you can boot from, you will need to [capture the image to a .wim file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744389%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), then [create a fixed size VHD and apply the .wim image to it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744338%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: For ImageX (which will create .wim file) I have to download this http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5753 Correct?

Comment: Yes, it's contained in the Windows AIK.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I will go for it. But I am still curious to know isn't there any way in Windows 7 GUI to create fixed type VHD of current windows?

Comment: I ran it imagex /capture c: g:\capturedImage.wim "My Image" but I am getting "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."